# SSRS Report: Multiple Charts to Export to 1 PowerPoint slide

Tags: reporting-services, charts, export, powerpoint, ssrs-2017

I currently am using Visual Studio SSDT 2017 for my SSRS Reporting. I currently have a SSRS report with 4 separate line graphs. Is there a way to get all 4 line graphs to export onto 1 PowerPoint slide? Say 1st line graph is in upper left corner, 2nd line graph is in upper right corner, 3rd line graph is in lower left corner and 4th line graph is in lower right corner or something like that?

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: unless you design your report to be the same as your required output, I don't see how you can export it the way you want it.

Comment: As Harry hints towards, just layout the charts so they fit on a single page in your SSRS report design. You might have to put the whole thing int a rectangle but it should output onto a single slide in PowerPoint.